# Click function requires an extra click to fully execute. It should all happen in one click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that I'm using to filter elements on a page. It will check the data attribute of the clicked element against class names on the filtered objects (`.filter-boy`).

Since the features are broken up into Categories and Subcategories, I want to hide any `.subcategory` parent containers that are empty. So I check each of them and look to see if all children `chillins` are hidden, and if so, add a class `.fart-sacks` to the parent.

Pardon the stupid naming.

```js
$(".feature-dropdown li").click(function() {

  var value = $(this).attr('data-filter');
  if (value === "all") {
    $('.filter-boy').show('1000');
    $('.category_header').show('1000');
    $('header.persona').addClass('hidden');
  } else {
    $('header.persona').not('.' + value).addClass('hidden');
    $('header.persona').filter('.' + value).removeClass('hidden');
    $('.filter-boy').not('.' + value).hide('3000');
    $('.filter-boy').filter('.' + value).show('3000');
    $('.category_header').addClass('hidden');
    $('.feature-filter').addClass('selected');
    $('.feature-filter-small').addClass('selected');
    $('.subcategory').each(function() {
      var chillins = $(this).find('.filter-boy').is(':visible');
      if (!(chillins)) {
        $(this).addClass('fart-sacks');
        console.log(this);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Markup (Slim/Middleman)

```
           .feature-dropdown
              ul
                li.control data-filter="marketing"
                  | Sales & Marketing
                  .unfilter-boy.control title="Clear Filter" data-filter="all"

                li.control data-filter="product_management"
                  | Product Management
                  .unfilter-boy.control title="Clear Filter" data-filter="all"

                li.control data-filter="engineering"
                  | Engineering
                  .unfilter-boy.control title="Clear Filter" data-filter="all"

                li.control data-filter="customer_support"
                  | Customer Support
                  .unfilter-boy.control title="Clear Filter" data-filter="all"

                li.control data-filter="ux_design"
                  | UX Design
                  .unfilter-boy.control title="Clear Filter" data-filter="all"


- data.features_all.features.each do |c|
  section.magellan-container id="#{c.category}"
    .category_header.row.align-center.align-middle.collapse
      .small-12.medium-3.medium-offset-1.small-order-2.medium-order-1.columns
        h2 = c.category
        p = c.category_description
      .small-12.medium-7.medium-offset-1.small-order-1.medium-order-2.columns
        - if c.category_illustration && c.category_video
          video autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" muted="muted" playsinline="playsinline" height="100%" width="100%"
            source src="/images/features/#{c.category_video}.mp4" type="video/mp4"
            source src="/images/features/#{c.category_video}.webm" type="video/webm"

        - elsif c.category_video
          video autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" muted="muted" playsinline="playsinline" width="100%"
            source src="/images/features/#{c.category_video}.mp4" type="video/mp4"
            source src="/images/features/#{c.category_video}.webm" type="video/webm"

        - elsif c.category_illustration
          = image_tag "#{c.category_illustration}"
        - else
          | No Asset

    - c.sub_category.each do |sc|
      .subcategory.row.align-center.collapse
        .small-12.medium-4.columns
          .subcat_icon
            = image_tag "features/subcat_icons/#{sc.icon_name}.svg", :alt => "#{sc.sub_category_name}", :class => "subcat_icon svg"
          h3 = sc.sub_category_name
        .small-12.medium-6.columns
          .row.collapse.feature-container
            - sc.feature.each do |feat|
              -if feat.priority == "high"
                div class="#{feat.tags} #{feat.priority} cool-card-wide filter-boy small-11 medium-12 columns"
                  .cool-pic
                    - if feat.screenshot && feat.video
                      video autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" muted="muted" playsinline="playsinline" height="240" width="320"
                        source src="/video/#{feat.video}.mp4" type="video/mp4"
                        source src="/video/#{feat.video}.webm" type="video/webm"

                    - elsif feat.video
                      video autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" muted="muted" playsinline="playsinline" height="240" width="320"
                        source src="/video/#{feat.video}.mp4" type="video/mp4"
                        source src="/video/#{feat.video}.webm" type="video/webm"

                    - elsif feat.screenshot
                      = image_tag "/images/features/#{feat.screenshot}"

                    - else
                      | NO ASSETS

                  .cool-wrapper
                    h4 = feat.feature_name
                    p = feat.feature_description
                    - if feat.url
                      a.learnmore href="#{feat.url}" Learn More
              -else
                .small-11.medium-6.columns.filter-boy class="#{feat.tags}"
                  div class="#{feat.priority} cool-card"
                    h4 = feat.feature_name
                    p = feat.feature_description
                    - if feat.url
                      a.learnmore href="#{feat.url}" Learn More
```

So what's happening is that the filter action is happening, but the `subcategory` function isn't firing *UNLESS* I click the `.feature-dropdown li` once more.

I am not a smart jQuery boy so please be patient with me.

Comment: please share html as well

Comment: Updated the post above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You show/hide `.filter-boy` elements over a span of 3000ms but you're checking `.filter-boy` element visibility in the `subcategory` callback function before the animation completes. The `subcategory` function fires on the second click because the 3000ms animation from the first call is complete and the element `.is(':visible') === true`.

Your first option is to wait for the `show()` to complete before you run the `subcategory` function. Luckily jQuery already provides [a way to do this](http://api.jquery.com/show/#show-duration-complete).

```
$('.filter-boy').filter('.' + value).show('3000', function(){
  //This fires AFTER the 3000ms transition completes
  $('.subcategory').each(function() {
    var chillins = $(this).find('.filter-boy').is(':visible');
    if (!(chillins)) {
      $(this).addClass('fart-sacks');
      console.log(this);
    }
  });
});
```

However, you already identify the `.filter-boy` elements that you wish to make visible using `$('.filter-boy').filter('.' + value).show('3000');`. So you could use a similar approach in your `subcategory` function which doesn't rely on the animation being complete or the element being visible in the DOM:

```
$('.subcategory').each(function() {
  //this is the collection you .show() and is query-able BEFORE the animation completes
  var chillins = $(this).find('.filter-boy.' + value); 
  if (!(chillins)) {
    $(this).addClass('fart-sacks');
    console.log(this);
  }
});
```

Comment: That's the one. A buddy of mine helped me offline and saw the same issue. Good eye!